# Symfony2 - override template bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I want to override the default SonataAdmin Template.

I create a standard_layout.html.twig in my Namespace/bundle/resources/views
(same structur, same file name, same content)

I copied all the content of the source template in my target template, i just edit some part of the target off course....and nothing

thanks for your help
Bye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the solution of bundle heritance http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html which allows, not only override templates but methods too.

Or you have http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates which focusing only on templates.

With this last, you can try to create :

```
app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig
```

Comment: I got this inside my source code: <!-- START fieldName: imageName template: zebBlogBundle:Default:base_show_field.html.twig compiled template: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig -->
<th>Image Name</th>
<td>Lighthouse.jpg</td>
<!-- END - fieldName: imageName --> but want to add this: <img alt="toto" src="/uploads/media/{{ imagename }}">